# sklearn.externals joblib throws ImportError - no module named joblib.numpy_pickle on a server

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sap-cloud-platform

I am struggling with a joblib issue.

I need to push inference application to a remote server, and I also need to load a saved standard scaler, because if I try to fit, i get an out of memory exception. I can't make phisical changes to the server, as it is a **sap cloud foundry instance**, and I don't see a way to solve it.

**Traceback from server:**

```
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "app.py", line 40, in <module>
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     standard_scaler = joblib.load('./datascaler.save')
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 598, in load
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 526, in _unpickle
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     obj = unpickler.load()
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     dispatch[key](self)
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1096, in load_global
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     klass = self.find_class(module, name)
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR   File "/home/vcap/deps/0/python/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1130, in find_class
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR     __import__(module)
   2019-08-05T15:34:41.54+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR ImportError: No module named joblib.numpy_pickle
```

From what I have seen on similar posts, **joblib version conflict/mismatch** might be a cause, but I can't really do anything with this, since its not my local machine that has this error.

Is there any other way to save the scaler, or to solve this conflict?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797769/no-module-named-numpy-pickle-when-executing-script-under-a-different-user Try this

Answer (score 1):

i also encount this problem. there may be two reasons.

1. the mode saved with `sklearn.externals.joblib` while loading with `joblib`. (sklearn.externals.joblib and joblib are different libs)
2. both `sklearn.externals.joblib` are used in save and load stage. however, they are different `scikit-learn` versions. such as, in save stage `scikit-learn==0.19.1` while in load stage `scikit-learn==0.21.x`.

the best way to repair it is use joblib with same versions. sklearn.externals.joblib will be removed in future version.